# TeamCity Agent Missing DotNetFramework4.0_x86, but not?

Tags: .net, teamcity, windows-server-2008-r2

I've been trying to move our TeamCity install from an old server onto a new Windows Server 2008 R2 server, I've finally got everything configured. However the build agent is saying that `DotNetFramework4.0_x86` isn't available on the build agent, but .NET 4.0 framework is installed.

Has anyone come across this issue, is it a Windows Server 2008 R2 thing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your build agent seems to failed to autoupgrade. 
Do the following:

- stop agent
- kill all java processes
- remove agent/system, agent/plugins, agent/tools folders
- start agent service
- wait for agent to update. This could take 5-10 minutes and build agent service may be shown as stopped.
- check agent/logs/update.log for errors

Please attach agent/logs folder to teamcity-feedback@jetbrains.com

Make sure build agent running windows service user account has rights to start/stop agent service and update all files under build agent installation directory

Comment: Thanks, I found a forum post that outlined this process, seemed to work.

Comment: This was also outlined here: [on jetbrains forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/304217;jsessionid=F970CF2847506C049FA116CE2599B300?tstart=31), but has the deviation that you only delete the plugins directory. I deleted all three directories mentioned above and restarted the service with success. 

NOTE: Just deleting the *contents* of the plugins directory doesn't work.

Comment: I also needed to make sure I use the http://IP:8111 and not  http://dns  which went through ARR (Application Request Routing - reverse proxy). Perhaps it uses other protocols beside HTTP on the same port

Answer (score 0):

Also check Programs and Features list in Control Panel that both **Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile** and **Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended** packages are installed - MSBuild and other required development tools are included in Extended package.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and installed this version of .NET framework 4.
by installing this it solve my problem. You also give it a shot.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17718

Answer (score 0):

I tried the method in the accepted answer but unfortunately it did not work.

What worked was that I disabled all build steps in my configuration and then turned them back on one at a time till I found one that caused the build agent requirements to fail with the .NET framework 4.0 thing.

Turns out mine was a Nuget Installer step. I had Nuget 2.7.x and according to this page: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/NuGet+Installer Nuget 2.5x+ requires .NET 4 and Nuget 2.8.6+ requires .NET 4.5+

Once I updated to the latest Nuget command line (Team City admin has a page for this), my build took off.