# TeamCity - Unmet requirements (DotNetFramework4.0_x86)

Tags: .net, teamcity

I recenlty updated my TeamCity to the newest Version. (10.0 build 42002)

Since then the build agent can't build any of my projects.

The agent tells me the following:

```
Unmet requirements: DotNetFramework4.0_x86 exists
```

To solve this problem I already did what was suggested in this stackoverflow question:
[TeamCity Agent Missing DotNetFramework4.0_x86, but not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330858/teamcity-agent-missing-dotnetframework4-0-x86-but-not)

Sadly it doesn't work. So I looked at the log files but didn't find anything weird. 
Then I looked at the agent configuration paramets. I found this:

```
DotNetFramework4.6.01055_x64_Path    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
DotNetFramework4.6.01055_x86_Path    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
DotNetFramework4.6_x64               4.6.01055
DotNetFramework4.6_x64_Path          C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
DotNetFramework4.6_x86               4.6.01055
DotNetFramework4.6_x86_Path          C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

As you can see the .NET 4.0 Framework is mapped to *DotNetFramework4.6*. For me this seems to be the problem.

Has someone an idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Just in case this helps anyone, I just ran into this and was able to resolve it by simply restarting the teamcity build agent windows service .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I used the work around from Greg B found [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FTW-46352#tab=Comments) to solve the problem.

To get the agent back running you need to insert following lines to the config of the agent. (For example located here: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\conf\buildAgent.properties)

```
DotNetFramework4.0_x86_Path=C\:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319
DotNetFramework4.0_x86=4.0.30319
DotNetFramework4.0_x64_Path=C\:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319
DotNetFramework4.0_x64=4.0.30319
```

1. I stopped the agent in the windows services
2. I pasted the parameters in the buildAgent.properties
3. I started the agent in the windows services

As far as I understand JetBrains fixed a bug in TeamCity and because of this the .NET Frameworks will not be found anymore.

Quote from Evgeniy Koshkin

> ...in case your tool targeting .net 4.0 as its required runtime you
>   actually should avoid installing .net 4.5(6) on your build agents. in
>   that case TeamCity will report that .net 4.0 runtime is available. But
>   i don't think this limitation of installed .net version makes sence in
>   most of the cases. Before this bug was fixed TeamCity reports the fact
>   '.net 4.0 was previously a runtime on this agent' as '.net 4.0 is a
>   runtime on this agent'. It's a buggy behaviour in my point of view.

Comment: 2 days to figure this out. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 7):

Ok, looks like it was a bug with the xUnit test runner plugin.  It's talked about on the TC issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-46352

The plugin author has already fixed it, you need to upgrade to v 1.1.2: https://github.com/carlpett/xUnit-TeamCity/releases/tag/1.1.2

You can upgrade by installing the .zip file according to: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Installing+Additional+Plugins

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I don't have the plugin "xUnit" installed. So this can't be the problem, or am I wrong?

Comment: Check your build steps and disable them until the agent requirement goes away.  That is the step adding the requirement, it might be a different Unit Test runner (or another plugin).

Answer (score 1):

The .NETFramework 4.0 and 4.6 are using the same directory

```
DotNetFramework4.0_x64   4.0.30319
DotNetFramework4.0_x64_Path  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
DotNetFramework4.0_x86   4.0.30319
DotNetFramework4.0_x86_Path  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

DotNetFramework4.6_x64   4.6.01055
DotNetFramework4.6_x64_Path  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
DotNetFramework4.6_x86   4.6.01055
DotNetFramework4.6_x86_Path  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

There is two possibles solutions for that:

- Install the .NETFramework 4.0
  ( https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851 )
  There can be both .NET Framework 4.0 and 4.6 installed on your system.
- Fix your agent requirement in your build configuration.

Comment: I have .NET Framework 4.0 and .NET Framework 4.6 installed. 
With "fix the agent requirement " you mean going to the Project Settings/Agent Requirements? I saw this solution in another stackoverflow answer but I can't change the requirements there. There is only an option to add new requirements.

Comment: I just upgraded to v10 and am getting this problem.  I don't have DotNet 4.0 installed but my project builds with 4.5 and built fine on v9.x.  It seems like the dotnet4.0 requirement is auto-added by the MSBuild build step (I don't have 4.0 selected) and I cannot figure out how to remove it.

Comment: Actually it looks like the requirement is being added by the xUnit test runner, even though I have 4.5 selected.

Comment: Ok, it was a bug and it's been fixed, I'll post an answer.