# TeamCity 10 and xUnit

Tags: teamcity, xunit.net

I had the same problems as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695121/teamcity-unmet-requirements-dotnetframework4-0-x86 after upgrading my teamcity to 10.0 (build 42002) today. I followed the instructions to update my xUnit plugin to v1.1.2 but now my build agent doesn't start to work. If I want to check the Agent Requirements of my build configuration I get the following error:

```
Unexpected Error

This was not supposed to happen. Please provide the error details to your TeamCity server maintainer.
If you maintain this TeamCity installation please report this error to JetBrains.

Error message: none available
TeamCity: 10.0 (build 42002)
Operating system: Windows Server 2012 R2 (6.3, x86)
Java: 1.8.0_66-b17 (Oracle Corporation)
Servlet container: Apache Tomcat/7.0.68

Trace: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at se.capeit.dev.xunittestrunner.XUnitTestRunType.getRunnerSpecificRequirements(XUnitTestRunType.java:86)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.runType.RunTypeWithExtensionsImpl.getRunnerSpecificRequirements(RunTypeWithExtensionsImpl.java:27)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.SBuildRunnerDescriptorImpl.getRunTypeRequirements(SBuildRunnerDescriptorImpl.java:3)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.build.steps.BuildStartContextBase.getEnabledRequirements(BuildStartContextBase.java:28)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.RawCompatibilityCalculator.matchRequirements(RawCompatibilityCalculator.java:42)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.RawCompatibilityCalculator.calculateInternal(RawCompatibilityCalculator.java:18)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.RawCompatibilityCalculator.access$000(RawCompatibilityCalculator.java:6)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.RawCompatibilityCalculator$1.run(RawCompatibilityCalculator.java:1)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.auth.SecurityContextImpl$2.run(SecurityContextImpl.java:1)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.auth.SecurityContextImpl.runAs(SecurityContextImpl.java:35)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.auth.SecurityContextImpl.runAs(SecurityContextImpl.java:10)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.auth.SecurityContextImpl.runAsSystem(SecurityContextImpl.java:34)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.RawCompatibilityCalculator.calculateCompatibility(RawCompatibilityCalculator.java:10)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildPromotionImpl$CandidatesCache.getCompatibilityMap(BuildPromotionImpl.java:23)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildPromotionImpl.getCompatibilityMap(BuildPromotionImpl.java:894)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTypeImpl.doGetCompatibilityMap(BuildTypeImpl.java:856)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTypeImpl.getCompatibilityMap(BuildTypeImpl.java:262)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.buildType.RequirementsBean.<init>(RequirementsBean.java:9)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.EditableRequirementsBean.<init>(EditableRequirementsBean.java:12)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.EditableBuildTypeSettingsForm.reloadRequirementsBean(EditableBuildTypeSettingsForm.java:89)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.AdminEditRequirementsController.getModelAndView(AdminEditRequirementsController.java:18)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.AbstractEditBuildTypeController.doGet(AbstractEditBuildTypeController.java:51)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseFormXmlController.doHandle(BaseFormXmlController.java:60)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseController.handleRequestInternal(BaseController.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.maintenance.TeamCityDispatcherServlet.service(TeamCityDispatcherServlet.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.DisableSessionIdFromUrlFilter.doFilter(DisableSessionIdFromUrlFilter.java:8)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:107)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.diagnostic.web.DiagnosticFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.DependencyParametersCalculationContextFilter.doFilter(DependencyParametersCalculationContextFilter.java:1)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:73)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.DelegatingFilter.doFilter(DelegatingFilter.java:2)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.web.ResponseFragmentFilter.doFilter(ResponseFragmentFilter.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1757)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1716)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Has somebody experienced or even fixed the same problem after upgrading the xUnit plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. I had to go to the build steps of the configuration and update the values of the xUnit step. Because of the plugin update some of the values were null or didn't exist anymore. After I set new values for xUnit version and .NET runtime it is working again.