# TeamCity Build Agent (v27767) deletes MsBuild.exe on run

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, teamcity, auto-update

TeamCity 8.0.6 CI box with build agent has been purring along for several years. After a system restart, TeamCity seems to have auto-upgraded the local build agent to version 27767. No other configuration changes were made, but this error now shows on build trigger:

```
Unable to find MSBuild at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe, please check MSBuild environment variable to target to Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0/3.5/4.0 or Mono installation directory
```

I RDP'd into the box and see that MSBuild.exe went missing - strange. So I re-add it from a local install and retrigger a build. As soon as the build agent picks up the file, it disappears! Happens every time. Maybe Windows is protecting this folder?

The build agent then becomes "incompatible". I tried this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38712136/198927), but this doesn't stop `msbuild.exe` from being deleted.

I checked that there are no odd steps in my build configuration. What could be deleting or moving MSBuild?

Comment: Can it be that the file is deleted not by TeamCity, but something else, like the build script? I'd try using SysInternals Process Monitor to capture the deleting event and check the originating process.